Special idempotent functions
Given any real number $x$, define $f(x)= \lfloor{x}\rfloor$ as the integer part of $x$, and $g(x)=x-f(x)$ as the fractional part of $x$. It's known that both $f$ and $g$ are idempotent functions with $f\circ g = g \circ f = \mathbf{0}$.
Out of curiosity, I've tried to find other idempotents function satisfying the properties above.
If  $f$ is linear, then $g$ is also linear, and $f(g(x))= f(x-f(x))=f(x)-f^2(x)=0$, $g(f(x))=f(x)-f(f(x))=0$ for all $x$ if $f$ is idempotent. This gives us $f=\mathbf{0}$ or $f=\text{id}_{\Bbb{R}}$ satisfying the conditions.
For non-linear $f$, I've only found $f(x)= \lfloor{x}\rfloor$ and $f(x)= \lceil{x}\rceil$ that satisfies the conditions. If we use different bases to express the real and then apply floor or ceiling function, it gives rise to even more (but essentially the same) function with the properties.
So here is my first question,

Is there any other pair of idempotent functions $f,g:\Bbb{R} \to\Bbb{R}$ that satisfies $x=f(x)+g(x)$ and $f\circ g = g \circ f =\mathbf{0}$? If there isn't any, how can we prove it?

If we change the domain and range to $\Bbb{C}$, $f(z)=\text{Re}(z)$, $g(x)=i\cdot\text{Im}(z)$, also satisfies the condition.
Let $V$ be an inner product space, $W$ be an arbitrary subspace of $V$. The pair of idempotent linear transformation $(f,g)$ defined by $v=f(v)+g(v)$ for all $v\in V$, where $f(v)\in W$, $g(v)\in W^\perp$, also has this properties.
From the examples above, these kind of idempotent functions seem to have special function that splits things into two parts being independent of (or irrelevant to) each other in some sense. I am aware that maybe it's just because of the way we defined it to be, but is there any deeper meaning under it? Sorry for asking this question in such an unclear way.

Nice question! First, here is a general discussion of the linear case. Suppose $V$ is a vector space. Two idempotent linear maps $f, g : V \to V$ are said to be

orthogonal if $fg = gf = 0$, and
complementary if $f + g = 1$;

we say that $f$ is the complement of $g$ and vice versa. Note that if $f + g = 1$ then $fg = f(1 - f) = f - f^2 = 0$ and similarly for $gf$, so complementary idempotents are automatically orthogonal; this generalizes your calculation in the third paragraph. Then we have the following very nice fact:

Very nice fact about idempotents: Pairs $(f, g)$ of complementary idempotents on a vector space $V$ are in natural bijection with direct sum decompositions $V \cong V_f \oplus V_g$ of $V$, where $V_f = \text{im}(f) = \ker(g)$ and $V_g = \text{im}(g) = \text{ker}(f)$.

This is a nice exercise. With respect to this decomposition, $f$ is the projection $v = (v_f, v_g) \mapsto v_f$ onto the first factor, and $g$ is the projection $v = (v_f, v_g) \mapsto v_g$ onto the second factor. So your idea here:

From the examples above, these kind of idempotent functions seem to have special function that splits things into two parts being independent of (or irrelevant to) each other in some sense.

is exactly correct in the linear case. $V$ can also be a much more general structure than a vector space; it can be, say, a module over a ring, or an object in an abelian category.
This lets us write down some funny examples over $\mathbb{R}$ using the fact that it is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, together with the axiom of choice. Namely, the axiom of choice can be used to write down a direct sum decomposition
$$\mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{Q} \oplus \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$$
and then we can define $f$ to be the projection onto the first factor and $g$ to be the projection onto the second factor. This is some kind of decomposition of a real number into a "rational part" and an "irrational part," but note that it is highly non-unique (there isn't a unique way to pick a complement of $\mathbb{Q}$) and very strange, e.g. the rational part of a real number isn't guaranteed to be anywhere close to it. $f$ and $g$ here are $\mathbb{Q}$-linear but not $\mathbb{R}$-linear, and such functions are extremely poorly behaved (e.g. non-measurable); see Cauchy functional equation for more on this. More generally we can arbitrarily choose any $\mathbb{Q}$-subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ and arbitrarily choose any complement of it, and consider the corresponding projections.

This discussion doesn't actually cover the case of the floor function and the fractional part, which are not $\mathbb{Q}$-linear or even $\mathbb{Z}$-linear. To handle this case let's remove all available structure and just consider an idempotent map $f : X \to X$ on a bare set. What do idempotents look like in general? Well, first of all, they have an image $\text{im}(f)$, and by definition they fix all elements in their image (this is equivalent to being idempotent). Taking the fibers of $f$ partitions $X$ into a disjoint union of subsets
$$X = \bigsqcup_i F_i, F_i = f^{-1}(i), i \in \text{im}(f)$$
indexed by the image $\text{im}(f)$, where we also have $i \in F_i$ (since $f(i) = f(f(x)) = f(x) = i$ for some $x$). Conversely, given such a partition of $X$ into a disjoint union $\bigsqcup_i F_i$ together with a special point $i$ in each partition, we can write down a unique idempotent sending each subset $F_i$ to its special point $i$. So, we've learned:

Slightly less nice fact about idempotents: Idempotents on a set $X$ are in natural bijection with decompositions of $X$ into a disjoint union of subsets $\bigsqcup_i X_i$ together with a special point $i \in X_i$ in each subset.

Let's see how this works for the floor function and the fractional part:

For $f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor$, the image $\text{im}(f)$ is the integers $\mathbb{Z}$, and the fiber $f^{-1}(i)$ of $f$ over an integer $i$ is the half-open interval $[i, i+1)$. This partitions $\mathbb{R}$ into a disjoint union $\bigsqcup_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} [i, i+1)$ of half-open intervals, where the special point in $[i, i+1)$ is $i$.
For $g(x) = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$, the image $\text{im}(g)$ is the half-open interval $[0, 1)$, and the fiber $g^{-1}(j)$ of $g$ over $j \in [0, 1)$ is the translate $\mathbb{Z} + j$ of $\mathbb{Z}$. This partitions $\mathbb{R}$ into a disjoint union $\bigsqcup_{j \in [0, 1)} (\mathbb{Z} + j)$ of translates of $\mathbb{Z}$, where the special point in $\mathbb{Z} + j$ is $j$.

Now let's introduce a special point $0 \in X$, fixed by $f$, and a second idempotent $g : X \to X$, also fixing $0$, satisfying $fg = gf = 0$ (by which I mean the function which is identically $0$). What can we say about this situation? First of all, since $g$ is an idempotent the above analysis applies to it, so we have a disjoint union decomposition
$$X = \bigsqcup_j G_j, G_j = g^{-1}(j), j \in \text{im}(g)$$
and special points $j \in G_j$. The additional constraint that $fg = 0$ means exactly that $\text{im}(g) \subseteq F_0$, and symmetrically $gf = 0$ means exactly that $\text{im}(f) \subseteq G_0$. So the special points of $f$ must be contained within $G_0$, while the special points of $g$ must be contained within $F_0$; however, the other subsets $F_i, G_j$ for $i, j \neq 0$ are not really constrained. A large but manageable class of examples here is given by any decomposition of $X$ into a cartesian product
$$X \cong X_f \times X_g.$$
Then if we write $0 = (0_f, 0_g)$, we can take $f$ to be the "projection onto the first factor" $x = (x_f, x_g) \mapsto (x_f, 0_g)$ and $g$ to be the "projection onto the second factor" $x = (x_f, x_g) \mapsto (0_f, x_g)$, generalizing the linear case above. This makes the fibers of $f$ into copies of $X_g$ and vice versa. And this construction does handle the case of the floor function and the fractional part, which corresponds to a cartesian product decomposition
$$\mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{Z} \times [0, 1).$$
So let's restrict our attention to this case for simplicity.
The remaining thing to understand is the complement relation $f + g = 1$, and here I don't see a nice general story. To make sense of this the set $X$ has to be some kind of group or monoid; let's take it to be an abelian group. But $f$ and $g$ are not required to be linear. If we pick some arbitrary cartesian product decomposition $X \cong X_f \times X_g$ and define $f$ and $g$ with respect to it, then we have no reason a priori to expect that $f(x) + g(x) = (x_f, 0_g) + (0_f, x_g) = x$ unless $X_f, X_g$ are subgroups and this is a direct sum decomposition; but then we're back in the linear case.

Edit: Okay, here is a nice general story. Instead of trying to treat $f$ and $g$ symmetrically we are actually going to focus attention on $g$. Our starting point is the following observation: $g$ actually is additive if we think of it as taking values, not in the interval $[0, 1)$, but in the circle $S^1 \cong \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. The circle is part of a short exact sequence
$$0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \cong S^1 \to 0$$
which does not split, meaning $\mathbb{R}$ cannot be written as a direct sum $\mathbb{Z} \oplus S^1$ of groups (e.g. because $S^1$ has torsion but $\mathbb{R}$ does not). But $\mathbb{Z} \oplus S^1$ is itself a perfectly well-defined abelian group which happens not to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, but which behaves like a funny version of $\mathbb{R}$ in which every element has an "integer part" in $\mathbb{Z}$ and a "fractional part" in $S^1$ and both of these are exactly rather than approximately additive. The difference between $\mathbb{R}$ and this group is that fractional parts "add with no carries," so e.g. $\frac{2}{3} + \frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{3}$ here.
But we actually have well-developed machinery for understanding this "carrying" phenomenon, and describing the failure of short exact sequences to split. Here is what the story looks like in this particular case.
To avoid confusion we're going to need to name the quotient map $\mathbb{R} \to S^1$; let's call it $q$. We now pick a splitting $s$ of $q$ as a map of sets (not abelian groups), meaning a map satisfying $qs = \text{id}_{S^1}$. In this case it is exactly the fractional part map, but now thought of as a map $s : S^1 \to [0, 1)$. Since the short exact sequence does not split, $s$ cannot be additive. However, it still has the property that $g(x) = s(q(x))$ is idempotent (this is a general fact about splitting surjections) and that $f(x) = x - g(x)$ takes values in $\mathbb{Z}$ (since $q(x - sq(x)) = q(x) - qsq(x) = 0$ - remember that $q$ is still linear), and it still produces a cartesian product decomposition
$$\mathbb{R} \ni x \mapsto (f(x), q(x)) \in \mathbb{Z} \times S^1.$$
(This is a bijection because it has inverse given by $(a, b) \mapsto a + s(b)$.)
The point of going to all this trouble is that $g$ is automatically idempotent and $f + g = 1$ by definition, so the only remaining things to understand are why $fg = gf = 0$ and why $f$ is idempotent. The condition $fg = g - g^2 = 0$ just says that $g$ is idempotent (note that this does not require $f$ to be linear). And the condition $gf = (1 - f) f = 0$ is equivalent to the condition $f^2 = f$, and it is satisfied iff $g(f(x)) = s(q(f(x)) = s(0) = 0$, so it is necessary and sufficient that we pick the splitting $s$ to satisfy $s(0) = 0$, which is easy enough.
Generalizing, the upshot of this discussion is that we get a pair $f, g : A \to A$ of idempotent maps (not necessarily linear) on an abelian group $A$ satisfying $fg = gf = 0$ and $f + g = 1$ from the following data:

A subgroup $B$ of $A$, and
A set-theoretic splitting $s$ of the quotient map $q : A \to A/B$ satisfying $s(0) = 0$.

Specifically, we take $g = sq$ and $f = 1 - g$ as above. $f$ and $g$ are linear (over $\mathbb{Z}$) iff $s$ is linear iff the short exact sequence $0 \to B \to A \to A/B \to 0$ splits, exhibiting $A$ as a direct sum $A \cong B \oplus A/B$; this is the simpler linear case from above. When the short exact sequence does not split, or even if it does and we just pick a nonlinear splitting $s$, then $f$ and $g$ are nonlinear.
(This is not required for just the construction of the idempotents, but the failure of $s$ to be linear can be "measured" by the difference $s(x + y) - s(x) - s(y) \in B$, which is an example of something called a $2$-cocycle. These can be used to understand the behavior of central extensions, and generalize "carrying". The $2$-cocycle can be thought of as describing how far $A$ is from being the direct sum $B \oplus A/B$.)

Wow! Thanks for the detailed answer and the explanation! I haven't tried to see $\Bbb{R}$ as an abelian group or a set before asking this question. Looking at things from different perspectives really gives new ways to solve the problem. I've learned a lots from this. Thanks again!

@kerusunox: you're welcome! And thanks for asking the question, I enjoyed thinking about it. It's a tantalizing mystery that you ask for $f + g = 1$ but $f$ and $g$ are not linear and I wanted a good explanation of how this happens.
